# how to loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
symbols =['a','b','c']
for i in range(len(symbols)):
        formula= 'X~ age +' +symbols[i]+ '+'
        print(formula)
```

This will give an output like:

```
X~ age+ a+
X~ age + b +
X~ age + c +
```

But I need the output to be :

```
X~ age+a 
X~ age+a+b 
X~ age +a +b+c
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are the extra spaces in the last line of the output an absolute requirement?

Comment: @Paul Rooney no not at all its just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the previous strings seen.

```
symbols =['a','b','c']
prev = "+ "
for i in symbols:
        formula = 'X~ age {} {}'.format(prev,i)
        print(formula)
        prev += i + " + "

X~ age +  a
X~ age + a +  b
X~ age + a + b +  c
```

If you don't want spaces just remove them:

```
symbols =['a','b','c']
prev = "+"
for i in symbols:
      print('X~ age{}{}'.format(prev, i))
      prev += i + "+"

X~ age+a
X~ age+a+b
X~ age+a+b+c
```

You can also just iterate over the symbols directly, forget about indexing.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in general is to *accumulate*.

```
text = 'starter'
for symbol in symbols:
    text += symbol
    text += '+'
    print(text)
```

Because this is such a basic question I am not going to write out code that does *exactly* what you asked for.  You should be able to figure out how to modify the above to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you really want to do, but what about this:

```
items = ""
for elem in symbols:
    items = "{}{}".format(items, elem)
    print "X~ " + items
```

( it seems that you want to concat the elements of your array for each iteration; at least that is how I read your question)

Comment: Probably because your code prints `X~ aX~ abX~ abc`. You need to add the `+'s` in somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
symbols =['a','b','c']
formula='X~ age'
for i in range(len(symbols)):
        formula= formula + '+' + symbols[i]
        print(formula)
```

Assuming that the spaces in `X~ age +a +b+c` between `+a` and `+b` was by mistake.. else.. I dont find some pattern here and you need to loop again to print it that way..

Answer (score 0):

symbols = ['a','b','c']

output = "X~ age"

for i in range(len(symbols)):

```
if i != len(symbols) - 1:
    output = output + "+" + str(symbols[i])
    print output
else:
    output = "X~ age"
    output = output + " +" + str(symbols[0]) + " +" + str(symbols[1]) + "+" + str(symbols[2])
    print output
```

---

X~ age+a

X~ age+a+b

X~ age +a +b+c